# Run node_module package command in js file

Tags: node.js, node-modules

In the package.json file, I have a line in the `scripts` object like this:

```
"scripts": {
     // some commands..
     "runpackage": "someNpmPackage -args"
}
```

This `someNpmPackage` is a package I have in my node_modules, but not in the command line. (i.e. I can run the command in the terminal).

This works fine. However, I want to be able to do in the scripts: `"runPackage": "node scripts/runPackage.js"`

I try something like

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('someNpmPackage -args', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      process.exit();
    }
    console.log('success');
});
```

But all I get is, `/bin/sh: someNpmPackage: command not found`.

How can I make the `exec` function know about this package?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install the `someNpmPackage` globally in your system?

Comment: This is meant to run on a server that doesnt have that package in the command line.

Comment: You can do `npm install -g someNpmPackage` in the command line to install that package globally and be able to access it via command line.

Comment: But i dont want to install it globally! I dont have that access.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the root project folder, on the command line: `./node_module/.bin/someNpmPackage`. If this command works, then it should work with `exec`.

Comment: The command does work in `./node_modules/.bin` but not in the script. It says the command not found.

Comment: are you actually writing `./node_module/.bin/someNpmPackage` in the `exec` function? or just `someNpmPackage`

Comment: just `someNpmPackage`. It did work after I used `exec(path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/.bin') + '/someNpmPackage`